# contains duplicates function won't return true?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, recursion

Why doesn't "return true" work here? Instead the function returns undefined...

```
var containsDuplicate = function(nums) {
    let newArray = nums;
    let p = newArray.pop();
    if (newArray.includes(p)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (newArray) {
        containsDuplicate(newArray);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

EDIT:

I'm calling the function with something like this:

```
console.log(containsDuplicate([1,2,3,9,9,0]))
```

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/10768127. It's a much easier method

Comment: ...and the inner "containsDuplicate" does not return its value?

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to remove duplicates. With a Set for example. I'm specifically interested in this odd bug.

Comment: You forgot to return the recursive call

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed the missing return before the recursion...

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a return statement before the recursive function.

```
var containsDuplicate = function(nums) {
    let newArray = nums;
    let p = newArray.pop();
    if (newArray.includes(p)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (newArray) {
        return containsDuplicate(newArray);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should step through it with a browser debugger, but my opinion based on experience is that you may be setting newarray to null, which would happen if nums isn't declared correctly.  If newarray is null, the if check will throw an exception and not evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Because block with `containsDuplicate(newArray);` return nothing. Also function so bad because `newArray.includes(p)`. Use hashmap aka Object:

```
var keys = {}
for (let i = 0, c = arr.length; i < c; i++) {
   let v = arr[i];
   if (!keys[v]) {
       keys[v] = true;
   } else {
       return true;
   }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the recursive call

```js
var containsDuplicate = function(nums) {
  let newArray = nums;
  let p = newArray.pop();
  if (newArray.includes(p)) {
    return true;
  } else if (newArray) {
    return containsDuplicate(newArray);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

console.log(containsDuplicate([1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 0]))
```

For Remove Duplicate use `Array#filter`

```js
console.log(containsDuplicate([1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 0]))


function containsDuplicate(arr){
 return arr.filter((a,b)=> arr.indexOf(a)==b)
}
```